# Error while while compiling arm64 flutter engine

Tags: flutter, flutter-engine

I am having issues while compiling the engine.

I followed [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Compiling-the-engine) steps to compile the engine.

And have tried iOS simulator build with the following command:

`sudo ./flutter/tools/gn --ios --simulator --unoptimized  && sudo ./flutter/tools/gn --unoptimized && sudo ninja -C out/ios_debug_sim_unopt && sudo ninja -C out/host_debug_unopt`

**And it compiled fine** but it's **having issues with the android arm64** builds with the following command:

`sudo ./flutter/tools/gn --android --unoptimized --android-cpu=arm64 && sudo ./flutter/tools/gn --unoptimized && sudo ninja -C out/android_debug_unopt_arm64 && sudo ninja -C out/host_debug_unopt`

This is the last traceback of the error.

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kartik/Code/experiments/engine/src/out/android_debug_unopt_arm64/../../build/android/gyp/javac.py", line 345, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/Users/kartik/Code/experiments/engine/src/out/android_debug_unopt_arm64/../../build/android/gyp/javac.py", line 338, in main
    input_files + build_utils.GetPythonDependencies())
  File "/Users/kartik/Code/experiments/engine/src/build/android/gyp/util/build_utils.py", line 322, in GetPythonDependencies
    non_system_module_paths = [
  File "/Users/kartik/Code/experiments/engine/src/build/android/gyp/util/build_utils.py", line 322, in <listcomp>
    non_system_module_paths = [
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 375, in abspath
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
[24/80] ACTION //third_party/dart/runtime/v...form(//build/toolchain/android:clang_arm64
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Can anyone suggest to me what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed after updating the python version `3.9.7`